# is there a step by step guide to change/update from RESTkit 0.10.0 to RESTkit 0.20.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit, updating, restkit-0.20

I got an app that was running RESTkit 0.10.0 on iOS 5 and an old version of xcode, when I started to work on it on my xcode that its the recent version it gave me a ton of Warning, so I tried to solve them. I got most of them but I think that somethings might not work on the RESTkit anymore, i haven't experienced a fail I just think I messed up some functionalities that I probably dont need. I still have 11 warnings that i dont think i can get rid of and i think that changing to a more updated RESTkit will do the trick. does anyone know how to change the RESTkit in my project with all the settings? Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the official upgrade guide [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0).

Comment: should i only replace the code or is there something else i have to do?

Comment: Yes. There are a number of different classes between .1 and .2 so it isn't trivial.

Comment: now i get this error
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectMapping", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in myclassname1.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectManager", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in myclassname2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I did say the classes had changed and it wasn't trivial. You'll get this kind of build error for each of the classes that no longer exist.

Comment: i just added the libraries again but you need add only the libRestkit.a which is for iOS if you add any more you'll get another error!